# How to close eventSource with redux action in saga?

Tags: redux, server-sent-events, redux-saga, eventsource

I want to start and stop eventSource by buttons. Start button with CONSTANTS.FETCHING_STARTED action and stop button with CONSTANTS.FETCHING_STOPPED action.

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/940 - not works for me.

I've tried stop and start in one function, but it didn't work.

This is my saga.

```
import {
  call,
  take,
  takeLatest,
  put,
  race,
  cancelled
} from "redux-saga/effects";
import { eventChannel, END } from "redux-saga";

import * as CONSTANTS from "../constants";

export function* innerSSE(eventSrc) {
  const eCh = eventChannel(emitter => {
    eventSrc.onmessage = msg => {
      emitter(msg);
    };

    eventSrc.onerror = () => {
      emitter(END);
    };

    return () => {
      eventSrc.close();
    };
  });

  try {
    yield takeLatest(eCh);
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) eCh.close();
  }
}

function* start() {
  const eventSrc = new EventSource(CONSTANTS.STREAM_URL);
  const chan = yield call(innerSSE, eventSrc);

  while (true) {
    const msg = yield take(chan);

    yield put({
      type: CONSTANTS.FETCHING_IN_PROGRESS,
      payload: JSON.parse(msg.data)
    });
  }
}

function* stop(eventSrc) {
  // innerSSE.close()
}

export function* sseSaga() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const started = yield take(CONSTANTS.FETCHING_STARTED);

      yield call(start, started);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillUnMount()` => dispatch aciton => saga trigger

Comment: Could you add some explanations to your code? That will benefit OP, future readers and yourself -- might bring you extra upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function* main(){
  yield takeLatest(CONSTANTS.FETCHING_STARTED, function*(){
    // create event channel
    const chan = eventChannel(()=>{ /* ... */})

    yield takeEvery(chan, function*(){
        // process event
    })

    try{
        // waiting for FETCHING_STOPPED
        yield take(CONSTANTS.FETCHING_STOPPED)
    }finally{
        // or close by another FETCHING_STARTED
        chan.close()
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function eventSource(eventSource, events = []) {
    const subs = emitter => {

        eventSource.onmessage = (msg) => {
            //return emitter(msg);
        };

        eventSource.onerror = () => {
            return emitter(END)
        };
        console.log(events);


        eventSource.addEventListener('disconnect', (event) => emitter({type: 'DISCONNECT', payload: JSON.parse(event.data)}), false);

        events.map((eventType, index) => {
            console.log(eventType);
            return eventSource.addEventListener(eventType, (event) => emitter({type: eventType, payload: JSON.parse(event.data)}), false)
        });

        return () => {
            return eventSource.close();
        }
    };
    return eventChannel(subs);
}

   function* itemsEventSource(formData){
    let result;
    try {

        const params = new URLSearchParams();

        params.append('clientId', formData.clientID);
        params.append('access_token', formData.token);

        result = new EventSource([SOCKET, 'notify'].join("/") + "?" + params.toString());

        const channel = yield call(eventSource, result, [CONNECTED, DISCONNECTED, FETCH_SUCCESS, 'NOTIFY']);

        while (true) {

            const action = yield take(channel);

            yield put(action);

        }

    } catch (error) {
        yield put({type: CONNECT_FAILED, error: error.message});
    }
    return result;}

    function* watchItemsEventSource() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const {payload} = yield take(CONNECT);

            const [connect, cancel] = yield race(
                [
                    call(itemsEventSource, payload),
                    take(CONNECT_FAILED)
                ]);

            console.log(connect, cancel, payload);

        } catch (error) {
            yield put({type: ERROR, error: error.message});
        }
    }}

    export function *moduleASaga(){
       yield all({[ fork(watchItemsEventSource)]})   }
```